# plot the theoretical cdf

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am trying to plot the empirical cumulative distribution function and theoretical cumulative distribution function. This is my R code:

```
x=rgamma(40, 2, 1/3)
plot(ecdf(x))
lines(x, pgamma(x, shape = 2, scale = 3), type="l", col = "red")
```

But I got the graph in the attached file which I think it is not reasonable.
What I do wrong?
[image]

Comment: Your proposed theoretical CDF (red) isn't monotonic. Why do you think that is? What do you notice if you print `x`?

Comment: You may find the `curve()` function helpful.  It may take the place of `lines()`.  [See this blog](http://jeromyanglim.tumblr.com/post/33554937336/how-to-plot-cumulative-distribution-function-in-r) for implementation.

Comment: Pay attention to the ordering of x.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on my comment... is this what you are looking for?

```
x=rgamma(40, 2, 1/3)
plot(ecdf(x))
curve(pgamma(x, shape = 2, scale = 3), 
      0, 30, 
      add=TRUE,
      col="red")
```

This results in the following plot:

[image]